# I am trying to make an image stay put longer after an if statement occurs

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to edit my game so that when an if statement occurs an image appears, but the if statement only happens when the object hits the wall and the ball bounces off, so the image only appears for the amount of time the if statement is active. I tried to make a delay command but after the if statement occurs it freezes the entire game for the given time.

Does anyone know how to isolate a delay command or make the image stay visible for an extra second after the if statement expires/after the ball hits the wall and bounces off???

Here are the lines of code that has to do with this:

```
image_set = pygame.display.set_mode()
image = pygame.image.load("image.png")

def image():
image_set.blit(image,(600,90))

if object.left == (COLLISION_RANGE) or object.right == (WINDOWWIDTH COLLISION_RANGE):
        DisplayOoface()
        Oof.play()
```

Comment: Perhaps change the speed drastically as the ball approaches and departs the wall? That would cause the appearance of being slow without needing the actual "if statement" to be delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to "hide" the image into a separate function, Use the Threading package to create a new thread and pass that function in to be executed.

Within the function you can add a delay to the start of the code. When you start the additional thread within the if statement, you will have the delay you need, and then the function can hide the image.

If you do not thread this task, then python simply processes one line of code at a time. By passing off the task of waiting and hiding the image to a secondary thread, your main thread (the game) can continue functioning as needed.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html